# Process field with timestamp in Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm receiving messages from Google Cloud Pub/Sub with this format:

```
{u'date': u'2019-03-26T09:57:52Z', 'field1': value1, u'field2': u'value2', u'field3': u'value3', u'field4': u'value4',...}
```

And I would like that when this messages are processed in the pipeline with the window:

```
| 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(1 * 10))
```

The field 'date' will be processed as the reference timestamp of the window.

Would I need a custom WindowFn or How should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the custom timestamp like that:

```py
def custom_timestamp(message):
    # assuming that message is already parsed JSON (dict)
    import datetime as dt
    import apache_beam as beam
    ts = dt.datetime.strptime(message["date"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    return beam.window.TimestampedValue(message, ts.timestamp())
```

and then:

```py
| 'CustomTimestamp' >> beam.Map(custom_timestamp)
| 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(1 * 10))
```

You can find full details in here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#adding-timestamps-to-a-pcollections-elements

You must note however, that Streaming Python SDK for Apache Beam has a lot of missing parts and some things are not working as you might expect. I've wanted to implement exactly the same case that you have and after adding custom timestamps, DataFlow Runner **dropped my messages** due to something they call *droppedDueToLateness*. I'm still not sure whether it's possible to set a system watermark to process historical data using PubSub and Python.

Comment: Thank you Marcin. I finally take the current date instead of the element data (I have 2 windows in the pipeline) with the following code:  `yield beam.window.TimestampedValue(element,time.mktime(datetime.datetime.today().timetuple()))`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't need to specify custom TimestampedValue once you stick to "current date" as it's a default behaviour.

Comment: I do that because in the first windows of 10 secs. I use the pubsub timestamp. After that windows finish I need to add a new timestamp to the element of the output pcollection.If you think is a good idea to review this use of case I can add the pipeline to the main post.